# How to run multiple .trace files in one run i.e one after the other in UI automation tool?

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Iam having five .trace files and now i want to run all the the test cases in one click. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You must copy all from your .trace file and save it in testEditor like .js file. After that you can use yours  .js files like #import ".../fileName.js"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding your script files into separate trace documents, I'd recommend putting your scripts into separate text files and then have a single master script file that imports them like so:

```
// In master.js
#import "test1.js"
#import "test2.js"
// etc…
```

So, the other files (test1.js, test2.js, etc) have your actual test cases. Now, you can choose "import" from the "Add" button in the scripts panel on the left sidebar and select your `master.js` file. When you run, it will import all the other script files and run them in order.